# this keyword inside $.ajax() to call other function to setup url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using following code for ajax calls

```
return $.ajax({ 
    type: this.setType(), 
    url: this.setUrl() 
});
```

My question is regarding `this` keyword. Will `this` keyword work in my above case or should I save it reference in other variable such as `self` in order to make above code work?

Comment: Just a note: I'm wondering why you are using setters for getting the ajax parameters. Shouldn't they be getters?

Answer (score 2):

It will work just fine. The calls to `setType` and `setUrl` are done within the current scope, as part of the object initializer, and then that object is passed into `$.ajax`.

Here's how that code is evaluated:

```
var obj = {};
obj.type = this.setType();
obj.url = this.setUrl();
var rv = $.ajax(obj);
return rv;
```

Since you never introduce a new scope (never create or enter a new function), `this` is not changed.